# Getting the error object from the server Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I have a question regarding error handling in Angular 7.

I have a global validation handling in backend and the returned object looks like that in postman:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "prop1": [
            "Required"
        ],
        "prop2": [
            "Required"
        ]
    },
    "type": "ValidationException",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Validation failed",
}
```

But I am not getting the same object in Angular, rather the default error from Angular where all these properties are missing. So, I cannot know which property contains the problem and what was missing.

I have tried to work with intercepter:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        // my code
          return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

And with error handler:

```
export class ErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
   constructor() { }
   public handleError(error: any) {
       if (error && error.errors) {
           // custom handling
       }
   }
}
```

and both errors are not having the information that the server is sending.

Is it possible in somehow to get the same structure in Angular? or is this a dead end? and if so, what are the alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: what is an angular "default error"?

Comment: Well, actually, it was my mistake. I was receiving an internal not handled error from Server and that is why I wasn't seeing the body of the error I wanted. It is done now! Thanks